# Getting wrong file path using "registerForActivityResult"

Tags: android, filepath, filepicker

```
mGetContent =
            registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.GetContent(),
                    uri -> {
                        if(uri!=null) {
                            noticeUri = uri;
                            textViewNoticeName.setText(uri.getPath());
                        }
                        else{
                            Toast.makeText(CROption.this, "No file selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
```

Launching picker like this:

```
mGetContent.launch("application/pdf");
```

It's working in android 10. But in android 7(emulator), it is showing wrong path like this
Choosing this file
[image]

Getting path like below:
[image: Wrong path]

I can read file size and can also upload the file in cloud storage. But I can't read the file name , file type and correct path.
`haven't taken storage permission`.
**I want to allow user to select a pdf file for uploading**. I need the `file name` and `type` for this.
I haven't worked in storage before.

Comment: uri.getPath() does not deliver a file system path as you can see. Have a look at uri.toString() to see a nice content scheme. But still no file system path.

Comment: @blackapps How can I get file system path?

Comment: You should not hunt for a path. Use the uri directly to upload the file.

Comment: Actually I want to show the path to user. By the way it is not important. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get file name like this:

```
  Cursor returnCursor =
        getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
  int nameIndex = returnCursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME);
   returnCursor.moveToFirst();
textViewNoticeName.setText(returnCursor.getString(nameIndex)));
```

You can get filetype like this:

```
 String mime=getContentResolver().getType(uri);
```

Comment: Working. Can you please explain the code? By the way is there any way to get extension without using file name?

Comment: Read this:https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/retrieve-info